# What is and how to determine the calling context of an invoked method or function within another function?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, call

What is the calling context of an invoked method or function within another function?

In browsers, the default calling context is the `window` object. In various situations, how do I avoid this?

If a function is invoked -- for example, by `theFunction();` -- within a containing function, is the invoked function's calling context the containing function?

In these two examples

```
(function ()
{
    something.initialize();
}());
```

and

```
(function ()
{
    something.initialize.call(this);
}());
```

..., is the calling context the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same. *In the following I assume you were talking about `this` when you mentioned context.*

In the first example, inside `initialize`, `this` will refer to `something`. In the second one, it will refer to the global object, which is `window` in browsers.

---

What `this` refers to is determined by how the function was called. There are five cases:

- `func()`, calling a function "standalone": `this` refers to the global object.
- `new func()`, calling a function as constructor method: `this` will refer to an empty object which inherits from `func.prototype`.
- `obj.func()`, calling a function as property of an object: `this` will refer to the object `obj`.
- `func.apply(foo)`, `func.call(foo)`, invoking a function with `apply` or `call`: `this` refers to the object passed as first argument.

ECMAScript 5 also introduced [`.bind()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which enables you to bind `this` to a certain object, *without* immediately calling the function.

---

Now you understand why in your second example, inside `initialize`, `this` will refer to `window`:

The outer function is called "standalone" (first case), so `this` inside of it will refer to `window`. Next you are passing `this` to `call`, which sets `this` inside `initialize` to `window` (fourth case).

---

**Further reading:**

- [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this), explains all I write above with some examples.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not the same. The first parameter to the `call` method sets the value of `this` inside that function; example 1's `this` should theoretically contain a reference to `something`; example 2's `this` corresponds to the `this` of your self executing function.

Answer (score 2):

The environment available to a function when it is invoked is based on several things.

1. the `this` binding which is different for the initialize method in your example
2. the actual parameter bindings which are not and a binding for a special `arguments` object
3. a binding for the function name, if any
4. the environment chain at the time the function was created.  This is the "close" part of the term "closure".  A javascript function "closes over" all the variables that are in-scope when the function object comes into existence.

In your example, only 1 is affected by the choice to use `call` which has the effect of passing `this` instead of `something` as the `this` value in the method body.

The relevant part of the spec starts at section [10.4.3](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3)

> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution context for function code contained in function object F, a caller provided `thisArg`, and a caller provided `argumentsList`: ...

Answer (score 1):

Functions don't create context, unless it's a constructor (a function called with `new`).

In your second example the context is `undefined` (which gets transformed into the global object , `window`). In ES5 strict mode it won't be transformed into anything.

I recommend John Resig's [interactive JavaScript tutorial](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#22) on the topic of context.